# index out of bound when iterrow() how is this possible?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got error message:

```
5205
(5219, 25)
5221
(5219, 25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg2018/sa4.py", line 44, in <module>
    df.loc[idx,word]=len(df.iloc[indices[idx]][df[word]==1])/\
IndexError: index 5221 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5219
```

when I'm traversing the data frame, the index comes from the iterators. I don't know how is this even possible? `idx` directly comes from the dataframe

```
bt = BallTree(df[['lat','lng']], metric="haversine")
indices = bt.query_radius(df[['lat','lng']],r=(float(10)/40000)*360)

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    for word in bag_of_words:
        if word in row['caption']:
            print(idx)
            print(df.shape)
            df.loc[idx,word]=len(df.iloc[indices[idx]][df[word]==1])/\
                             np.max([1,len(df.iloc[indices[idx]][df[word]!=1])])
```

changing `iloc` to `loc` gives

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/Chu/Documents/dssg2018/sa4.py
(-124.60334244261675, 49.36453144316216, -121.67106179949566, 50.863501888419826)
27
(5219, 25)
/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg2018/sa4.py:42: FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
  df.loc[idx,word]=len(df.loc[indices[idx]][df[word]==1])/\
/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg2018/sa4.py:42: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  df.loc[idx,word]=len(df.loc[indices[idx]][df[word]==1])/\
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg2018/sa4.py", line 42, in <module>
    df.loc[idx,word]=len(df.loc[indices[idx]][df[word]==1])/\
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2133, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2173, in _getitem_array
    key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2023, in check_bool_indexer
    raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series provided as '
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Answer (score 7):

Your `index` is not from `0` to `len(df)-1`, this will making `df.iloc[idx]`out of boundary

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1]},index=[1,100])

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx)
    print(row)

1
a    0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
100
a    1
Name: 100, dtype: int64
```

Then when you do

```
df.iloc[100]
```

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

But when you do `.loc` you get the expected output.

```
df.loc[100]
Out[23]: 
a    1
Name: 100, dtype: int64
```

From the file :

`.iloc` :*iloc[] is primarily integer position based*

`.loc`:*.loc[] is primarily label based*

***Solution:***

Using `.loc`  or `df=df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: how should I fix this in this case?

Comment: @monotonic using loc

Comment: @monotonic btw , if my answer help, do not forget upvote and accept

Comment: @monotonic df=df.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: do you mean iloc or loc?

Comment: @monotonic I mean before run your code do `df=df.reset_index(drop=True)` and use your previous code

Comment: @monotonic I had the same issue, You should have applied something like dropna(). These functions drop some of the rows but don't update the index. Let's assume you have 3 rows with index1, index2, index3 in your dataframe. Also, let's assume index2 is NA. Using dropNa delets your second row in which index=2. then you have index1, index3 in your data frame. Thus, you always need to use reset_index() after particular functions such as dropna.